# Akka-http: How to get User-Agent header from request header?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I was trying to extract `User-agent` header from `Request-Header`, I tried this :

```
 headerValue(extractUserAgent) { userAgent =>

}


def extractUserAgent: HttpHeader => Option[String] = {
    case h: `User-Agent` => Some(h.)
    case x         => None
 }
```

I am stuck at line `Some(h.)`,I was thinking it might give some String values as `User-Agent` there, but not string values are inside of It.Help please!!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think you should read the documentation, its properly written and u can find your solution there:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/common/http-model.html

Comment: Answers should not just be links to documentation as it does not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

I finally got a solution

```
path("test") {
  get {
    headerValueByName("User-Agent") { header =>
      complete(s"""{ "User-Agent" : "${header}" }""")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example h is given to match any existing object which is given within . So unless `User-Agent` is an object to match against it will not work. You can update your code as below:

```
val uaHeader = "User-Agent".toLowerCase
def extractUA: HttpHeader => Option[String] = {
  case HttpHeader(`uaHeader`,value) => Some(value)
  case _         => None
}
```